# How do you show traffic and other layers in the new Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

On desktop, in the previous versions of Google Maps, you could see transit lines and traffic. I can't find these options in the new version of Google Maps. Where are they?

Comment: Can't post an answer, but I just discovered that while a search result or directions are showing, it's possible to click on a transit station (say a tram stop) and then the transit map layer is shown. Can't get both transit and traffic simultaneously, but it's a useful trick for me anyway...

Comment: I cannot post Answer but here is the solution as of 2015-12: Click "hamburger" (3 line) icon in upper left corner. A panel slides out from the left side, labeled "Google Maps". Second item in list is "Traffic" with an icon of a traffic light.

Answer (score 17):

The traffic option, if present in your city, is now under the Menu hamburger menu.

[image: Click on Menu hamburger menu]

---

[image: Select traffic]

Comment: Well, that is not always true.  If you have an active search term, you may not see this link.

Comment: Neither that "Traffic" box nor "Show traffic" link appears for me.

Comment: @BasilBourque I've updated the post

Answer (score 6):

The interface for showing traffic in the new Google Maps is very poor. The option to show the traffic layer is in fact under the search box, as @sathya says, but not always.

If you have searched for an address, the option is missing:
[image: New Google Maps, not traffic option visible]

Delete the address, and the option will appear:
[image: New Google Maps with traffic option visible]

The option is also available when you get directions. In fact, it is turned on when you ask for directions and have the car selected as your mode of transport. In this case, you'll have the option to hide traffic.
[image: Traffic visible with New Google Maps Directions]